# How to make a slider hearder?

Tags: plugins, html, headers

My goal is to make the same kind of header as the bottom part of [https://www.hotukdeals.com/'](https://www.hotukdeals.com/%27) header where you have an arrow on both sides and between them, all the categories that the website has. I don't know how to make such a sliding categories header. Is there a plugin that can make that, if yes, what is its name? Maybe I can do it with Elementor but I wouldn't have a clue how to do it with this plugin?

Thank you very much in advance for your answers!

Comment: Welcome to the WordPress Development community! Unfortunately, questions asking for product recommendations and those regarding third-party plugins are both off-topic here. You should reach out in Elementor's support channels, or more general communities

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.